# Почему Celery регистрирует задачи, но не выполняет их?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

Код предельно простой:

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery, shared_task

app=Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://user:pass@32.41.61.81:5672/vhost', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

start_task.py:

```
import tasks

r = tasks.add.delay(3, 3)
a = r.get()
print(a)
```

На сервере Ubuntu стоит RabbitMQ, Celery подключается к нему успешно, никаких проблем, вебверсия тоже работает без проблем. Через библиотеку *pika*
пробовал подключаться к RabbitMQ, отправлять сообщения и забирать их, тоже все хорошо, но если запускаю через Celery, то задачи не выполняются, просто висят в статусе "Получено".
Ставлю Celery и RabbitMQ первый раз, возможно какая то глупая ошибка, ниже прикладываю скрин из Flower
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ОС Windows? если да, то поставьте модуль eventlet (pip install eventlet) и запускайте воркер с параметром `-P eventlet`